# "Insert between two items" on 4clojure.com

Tags: clojure

This is 4clojure [question #132](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/132). The problem statement is: "Write a function that takes a two-argument predicate, a value, and a collection; and returns a new collection where the value is inserted between every two items that satisfy the predicate.".

I came up with the following solution:

```
(fn [pred value coll]
    (let [pairs (seq (zipmap coll (concat (rest coll) [0])))]
        (mapcat #(if (apply pred %) [(first %) value] [(first %)]) pairs)))
```

The first unit test on the site fails, whereas it passes locally on my machine. I'll reproduce the test here:

```
(= '(1 :less 6 :less 7 4 3) (____ < :less [1 6 7 4 3]))
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong? Is there some restriction that the site puts on solutions that I'm not adhering to? Or some other issue?

Comment: I'm not sure you need the extra 0 at the end of _pairs_ to build a solution. But as a side note a clever trick in Clojure to have pairs is `(map vector coll (next coll))`

Comment: The extra zero is because of the way zipmap works. I dont want to lose the last one. As a sidenote i got this solution working by replacing zipmap with `(partition 2 1 coll)` and a few other minor changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4clojure uses clojure version 1.4, and you are likely using 1.8 or 1.9 alpha.  There is a difference in the ordering of the result of `zipmap`, and this is the reason they are different.

```
;; 1.9 alpha 15:
(zipmap [1 2 3 4 5] [6 7 8 9 10])
=> {1 6, 2 7, 3 8, 4 9, 5 10}

;; 1.4:
(zipmap [1 2 3 4 5] [6 7 8 9 10])
=> {5 10, 4 9, 3 8, 2 7, 1 6}
```

Your solution happens to work on a more recent version of clojure, but you are relying on the ordering of a map when you use `zipmap`, and this is incorrect. The order of k-v pairs in a map is undefined, so your solution is only working by chance as you've currently implemented it.

Your solution will fail anyway if you're given an infinite sequence to process.  Consider a different approach where you build the sequence as you walk it.

Good luck!

Comment: incidentally the question doesn't ask for a lazy sequence to be returned, but you're right. I had originally tried to answer with a `reduce` based solution which worked until the last test runs.

Comment: also unless i'm wrong, I'm not able to directly use `lazy-seq` because that would require a named function which is also disallowed?

Comment: Write your fn like `(fn my-fn [x y z...] ...  (my-fn x y z...))`

Comment: Ah i thought you couldnt provide a name for `fn`, thanks.